# Unpivot with new column name

Tags: sql, sql-server-2012

**input table**

| Name | col1 | col2 | col3 | MaxMarkSub |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Tilak | 90 | 40 | 60 | col1 |
| Raj | 30 | 50 | 10 | col2 |
| Amal | 90 | 40 | 60 | col3 |
| Ramesh | 30 | 50 | 10 | col2 |

I want to get it arranged like the following:

| Name | col1 | col2 | col3 | mapping | output |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Tilak | 90 | 40 | 60 | col1 | 90 |
| Raj | 30 | 50 | 10 | col2 | 50 |
| Amal | 90 | 40 | 60 | col3 | 60 |
| Ramesh | 30 | 65 | 10 | col2 | 65 |

How can I achieve this?

Comment: Hi think you can do that by using simple CASE on SELECT : https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/language-elements/case-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15

Answer (score 0):

You can go for simple case expression.

```sql
SELECT name, col1, col2, col3, MaxMarkSub AS mapping, 
case MaxMarkSub when 'col1' then col1
               when 'col2' then col2
               when 'col3' then col3
               end as output
from TableName
```